# ROAuth - error in handshake - "You likely misentered your PIN..."

Tags: r, twitter-oauth

The following error is returned by the handshake, after its produced a valid token URL and I've entered the PIN.

`Error in cred$handshake() : 
  Invalid response after authorization.  You likely misentered your PIN, try rerunning this handshake & browser authorization to get a new PIN.`

I've triple-checked that I'm not mistyping the pin. Putting some prints inside the function suggests that 'oauth_token_secret' isn't in the response from oauthPOST()?

Code to reproduce and my system profile are below. Thanks in advance.

```
library(twitteR);
library(tm);
library(wordcloud);
library(RColorBrewer);
library(ROAuth);
library(RCurl);
library(digest);

##consumer key
twit_consumer_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
##consumer secret
twit_consumer_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
##request token URL
twit_request_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
##access token URL
twit_access_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
##authorize URL
twit_authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';

cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=twit_consumer_key,
                         consumerSecret=twit_consumer_secret,
                         requestURL=twit_request_url,
                         accessURL=twit_authorize_url,
                         authURL=twit_authorize_url);
cred$handshake();
```

And the following is the session info :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] digest_0.6.3       wordcloud_2.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.10.3        tm_0.5-8.3        
[6] twitteR_1.1.0      rjson_0.2.12       RCurl_1.95-4.1     bitops_1.0-5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 slam_0.1-28     tools_2.15.3
```

Comment: Whoops, copied a session info from earlier. ROAuth is loaded; ROAuth_0.9.2

Comment: I had my URLs switched around, idiot! Its okay now. thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks @David. I had made the exact same error. You can actually make that comment an answer to your own question, and accept it, to be in line with standard site usage.